# How CTE works internal in sql?

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I'm having a problem to track the Sequence of executing the following code :

**The Code is working fine**

Im just trying to understand how.

```
    with MyCTE(x)
    as
    (
  1)  select x = convert(varchar(8000),'hello') // line 1
    union all
  3)  select x + 'a' from MyCTE where len(x) < 100 //line 3
    )
    select x from MyCTE
    order by x
```

**MSDN:**

> The semantics of the recursive execution is as follows:
>
> Split the CTE expression into anchor and recursive members.
>
> Run the anchor member(s) creating the first invocation or base result
>   set (T0).
>
> Run the recursive member(s) with Ti as an input and Ti+1 as an output.
>
> Repeat step 3 until an empty set is returned.
>
> Return the result set. This is a UNION ALL of T0 to Tn.

**Stages:**

1) line 1 is executed  ( x=hello)

2) line 3 is executed (helloa)

3) now it calls itself so : here x is again back to hello !! ( line 1)

- according to : line **1** ,  whenever the cte calls itself - the x is always should be  reset ! ( or does the T0 is bypassed in the recursive?)
- what is the role for the (x) part it MyCTE(x) ? input or output ?

**quote:**

> Run the recursive member(s) with Ti as an input and Ti+1 as an output.

To my knowledge the (x) is the out value, not the Input.

Comment: Is this a theoretical question, or have you run this?

Comment: @gbn - Hi ! , I run this already and its working but I cant find out how.  - `whenever the cte calls itself - the x is always should be reset` , but it doesnt ( which is fine) but i cant find out why : it says each time : `select x = convert(varchar(8000),'hello')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

T0/Line1 is executed once as the anchor.

1. line 1 is executed (hello)
2. line 3 is executed (helloa) because LEN(hello) = 5  less then 100
3. line 3 is executed (helloaa) because LEN(helloa) = 6  less then 100
4. line 3 is executed (helloaaa) because LEN(helloaa) = 7  less then 100
5. line 3 is executed (helloaaaa) because LEN(helloaaa) = 8  less then 100
6. line 3 is executed (helloaaaaa) because LEN(helloaaaa) = 9  less then 100
7. line 3 is executed (helloaaaaaa) because LEN(helloaaaa) = 10  less then 100

...

With some comments

```
with MyCTE(x)
as
(
   select x = convert(varchar(8000),'hello')     -- Anchor, executed once
   union all
   select x + 'a' from MyCTE where len(x) < 100  -- Recursion, executed n times
)
select x from MyCTE order by x
```

At run time, this is

```
   select x = convert(varchar(8000),'hello')     -- Anchor
   union all
   select 'hello' + 'a'         -- Recursion 1
   union all
   select 'helloa' + 'a'        -- Recursion 2
   union all
   select 'helloaa' + 'a'       -- Recursion 3
   union all
   select 'helloaaa' + 'a'      -- Recursion 4
   union all
   select 'helloaaaa' + 'a'     -- Recursion 5
   ...
```

Comment: As always -  you are GREAT. thanks. the problem was that I thought that line `1` is ALWAYS get Executed....